# Can we get Yellowstone tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Worldbuilding has been doing rounds around Yellowstone:

The [geographical](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/963/if-yellowstone-experienced-another-level-8-eruption-on-the-vei-scale-what-are-t), and [geopolitical](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55847/how-will-geopolitics-be-affected-by-a-yellowstone-supervolcanic-eruption-in-2017) [consecuences](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55701/what-would-happen-to-earth-if-yellowstone-erupted) of the eruption has [been asked](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52445/geopolitical-and-economic-implications-of-a-large-eruption-at-yellowstone).

[How to defuse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/how-would-we-try-to-defuse-yellowstone) and [how to trigger it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40936/could-i-intentionally-trigger-a-yellowstone-eruption) has been asked too.

I don't know if Yellowstone is too narrow. I'm aware of the [volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volcanoes) tag.

Anyway, I submit this to the consideration of the community.

---

Edit:

[As I said to bilbo_pingouin](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/can-we-get-yellowstone-tag#comment10768_3983) the intention is not to separate Yellowstone. Instead the intention is to ease discovering these questions. The reason being that the consecuences questions have a lot of overlap and - even considering them different enough - people would benefit from reading the other questions and their answers.

I also agree on that a tag for supervolcanoes is more appropiate than a Yellostone one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [yellowstone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yellowstone) would be way too specific. [volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volcanoes) covers it pretty well.

But if it's really needed to get something to represent the sheer size of the problem, then, we might consider [super-volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-volcanoes). In history, there have been others than the Yellowstone. And in alternate worlds, there might be other ones. All those could gather under the [super-volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-volcanoes) tag, but certainly not under [yellowstone](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yellowstone).

At the end, a tag is used to classify the questions. And help specialist find the right ones. I pretty much doubt people interested in [volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volcanoes) would not be interested in [super-volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-volcanoes), or the other way around. So why separate them really?

Comment: I'm aware that there are others super-volcanoes. I guess you are right in that tag would be more appropriate. About the motivation, it is not to separate them, but to ease discovering them - I'll add that to the question. You made me think that perhaps hierarchical tags could serve well stackexchange.

Comment: Are super-volcanoes different enough from the broader category f volcanoes to warrant their own tag? Are tge interests/specializations that different? The flip side of creating the tag is having them *not* show up on the broader tag, unless we double-tag.  I, too, wish we had tsg hierarchies, but we don't.